# Deliberately slowing java servlet response time for testing

Tags: java, servlets

I wrote a little servlet (netbeans/payara) that delivers locally stored images for map creation to test my map compositing software.

Works perfectly, but a little too perfect due to the very fast response time. I would like to reduce my response time to better simulate a real world scenario with slow servers or bad connectivity.

Is there a good way to achieve this?

```
Thread.sleep()
```

would just block one thread, so that doesn't really help...

Comment: Have you considered throwing lots of requests at it using something like [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org) instead? That would be a lot more realistic.

Comment: Thank you for your your help, it is indeed a duplicate, i didn't search for apache, only for glassfish/payara so it didn't turn up in my search results. I will also take a closer look at JMeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.sleep()` won't make sleep just one thread. It will make sleep every thread that executes that code.

Comment: Thank you, i misread another answer regarding theads in servlets. I think in my (very basic) test case Thread.sleep will probably suffice, if not i will try the answers from the comments to my question.